# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}$ converges? or no

Tags: calculus

So, a series of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, but $a_n=2n^{-1}$ if n is even, but $a_n=2^{-n}$ if $n$ is odd. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n}$ converges? $2n$ is all even numbers, so it's $a_n=2(2n)^{-1}$. This is turned into $\frac{1}{n}$, which diverges, this is correct, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (sub)series for even terms is twice the sum of reciprocals of even natural numbers, i.e., the sum of reciprocals, which diverges. Thus the whole sum diverges.

Comment: twice${}{}{}$??

Comment: @Kenta, fixed. Thanks for noting my sloppyness.